# jboos 7 - standalone.xml gets overwritten at start

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

By default, in the standalone.xml file in jBoss 7.2 there is:

```
${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"
```

Obviously this works perfectly when you are developing in local. But when I try to deploy it in a non-local server, I change it to:

```
${jboss.bind.address.management:0.0.0.0}"
```

The first time works perfectly as well, but when you see again the standalone.xml it gets overwritten, do you know why?

Comment: Are you making the change while the server is running or when the server is shutdown?

Comment: this specify address allowed to access server, for local IP is 127.0.0.1 but for any non-local server it set pattern as 0.0.0.0 means server is accessible from any system.

Comment: It changes when is starting up by itself... it sesms that it takes the last configuration from the standalone history folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just leave it as default

```
${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"
```

You can pass IP address in args when you want to run JBoss.

```
standalone-fu-ha.xml -b xx.xx.xx.xx
```

Comment: This solution works perfectly but, is not any other way to do it without arguments? Thanks anyway for the response :)